# <iframe> - How to show the whole height of referenced page?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an application that I would like to embed inside our companies CMS. The only way to do that (I am told), is to load it in an `<iframe>`.

Easy: just set `height` and `width` to `100%`! Except, it doesn't work.

I did find out about setting `frameborder` to `0`, so it at least *looks* like part of the site, but I'd prefer not to have an ugly scrollbar *inside* a page that allready has one.

Do you know of any tricks to do this?

**EDIT:** I think I need to clarify my question somewhat:

- the company CMS displays the fluff and stuff for our whole website
- most pages created through the CMS
- my application isn't, but they will let me embedd it in an `<iframe>`
- I have no control over the `iframe`, so any solution must work from the referenced page (according to the `src` attribute of the `iframe` tag)
- the CMS displays a footer, so setting the height to 1 million pixels is not a good idea

Can I access the parent pages DOM from the referenced page? This might help, but I can see some people might not want this to be possible...

This technique seems to work ([gleaned](http://bytes.com/forum/thread91876.html) from several sources, but inspired by the [link](http://brondsema.net/blog/index.php/2007/06/06/100_height_iframe) from the accepted answer:

In parent document:

```
<iframe id="MyIFRAME" name="MyIFRAME" 
    src="http://localhost/child.html"
    scrolling="auto" width="100%" frameborder="0">
    no iframes supported...
</iframe>
```

In child:

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe() {

        var docHeight;
        if (typeof document.height != 'undefined') {
            docHeight = document.height;
        }
        else if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode != 'BackCompat') {
            docHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        }
        else if (document.body 
            && typeof document.body.scrollHeight != 'undefined') {
            docHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        }

        // magic number: suppress generation of scrollbars...
        docHeight += 20;

        parent.document.getElementById('MyIFRAME').style.height = docHeight + "px";    
    }
    parent.document.getElementById('MyIFRAME').onload = resizeIframe;
    parent.window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>               
</body>
```

**BTW:** This will only work if parent and child are in the same domain due to a restriction in JavaScript for security reasons...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either just use a scripting language to include the page into the parent page, other wise, you might want to try one of these javascript methods:

http://brondsema.net/blog/index.php/2007/06/06/100_height_iframe
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/Q_22840093.html

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your iframe is hosted on the same server as the containing page, you can [access it via javascript](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/).

There are a number of suggested methods for [setting the iframe to the full height of the contents](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JavaScript-Set-Iframe-Width-Height-Onload), each with varying degrees of success - a google for this problem shows that it's quite a common one, with no real, one-size-fits-all consensus solution i'm afraid!

Several people have reported that [this script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm) does the trick, but may need [some modification](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post258858-4.html) for your specific case (again, assuming your iframe and parent page are on the same domain).

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but adding `scrolling=no` as an attribute to the `iframe` tag normally gets rid of the scrollbars.

Comment: Yes, but then the embedded page gets cut off if it doesn't fit inside the iframe.